# Is a Conversion Operator Valid in this Case?

Tags: c++, oop, operator-keyword, conversion-operator

Usually, books usually discourage the use of conversion operators when wrapping up c structs. For example the c++ string, which is (believed to be) a wrapper of a C char array, does not provide a conversion operator. Instead it gives the the method `c_str()`.

However, I seriously think my case may be an exception. I am wrapping up an `SDL_Surface.` Here's the class declaration.

```
/** Wraps up SDL_Surface **/
class surface
{
    SDL_Surface* _surf;
public:
    /** calls SDL_LockSurface().
     ** throws surface_lock_exception on failure.
     **/
    void lock();

    /** calls SDL_UnlockSurface() **/
    void unlock();

    /** calls SDL_LoadBMP().
     ** throws image_load_exception on failure.
     **/
    void load_bmp(const string&);

    /** calls SDL_FreeSurface(). **/
    void free();

    /** destructor. Also free()s the internal SDL_Surface. **/
    ~surface();
};
```

In this case, I seriously think I should add a conversion operator to `SDL_Surface*` for easy compatibility with other SDL Functions that require an `SDL_Surface*`.

What do you think:

1. Would a conversion operator be prudent?
2. Or Should I use a method like `c_str()`?
3. Or is there another, better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although providing a conversion operator would be required to pass your new-fangled wrapper class to existing SDL library functions, you must ask yourself if you really need to.

The reason that `c_str()` exists at all is so that us C++ programmers can use `std::string` and then call all those archaic runtime library functions that never heard of it.  If you're writing a C++ program from the ground up, would any of your function calls take a `const char*`?  No, they'd take a `const std::string&`, perhaps.

So, if you are wrapping up SDL in a nice library, then one must ask if you should *ever* be exposing the underlying data structures.  Surely your library will always want to talk to a `Surface` and not care what is going on underneath?

So my preferred solution would be to hide it away and let those classes that deal with working with the underlying SDL library, do so.

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, You should provide a separate method.
The problem with conversion operator is that it might get called implicitly behind the scenes where you don't want/expect it to be used. Providing a special method guards you against this behiind the scenes magic.

Comment: Explicit type conversion is introduced in C++11, presumably this nullifies this reason for not using type conversion operators?

Comment: @hmjd: Yes itwould but the Q isn't tagged c++11 so I assume the OP works with C++03.

Comment: Als, I know it was not tagged C++11. Just wanted to confirm want I believed. Cheers.

Comment: @hmjd: No problem. Actually, moving to c++11 in real projects is going to take a while, the transition won't be quick.